# How to get the difference between 2 timestamps?

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 3.0.3 for this project.

I am trying to get the difference between two timestamps (clock in and clock out).

Here is the function attempting to do so:

```
public function clock_user_out()
{
    $this->db->where('USER_EMAIL', $this->session->userdata('USER_EMAIL')) 


    $data = $this->db->get('clocked_in_users'); 
    $uemail = $data->row()->USER_EMAIL;

    $uclockin = $data->row()->USER_CLOCK_IN;

    $uclockout = date(('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

    $uhours = $uclockout-$uclockin;

    $newdata['USER_EMAIL'] =  $uemail;

    $newdata['USER_CLOCK_IN'] = $uclockin;  


    $newdata['USER_CLOCK_OUT'] = $uclockout; 


    $newdata['USER_WORK_HOURS'] = $uhours;

    $this->db->insert('user_hours',$newdata);



    $this->db->where('USER_EMAIL', $this->session->userdata('USER_EMAIL'));     




    $this->db->delete('clocked_in_users'); 

}
```

I believe the error is when I am getting the variable $uhours by subtracting $uclockin from $uclockout.

There are 5 columns in the table I am working with.

1. ID [int]
2. USER_EMAIL [varchar]
3. USER_CLOCK_IN [timestamp]
4. USER_CLOCK_OUT [timestamp]
5. USER_WORK_HOURS [time]

Now for the one I tested these were the results.

- USER_CLOCK_IN = 2015-12-31 07:37:59
- USER_CLOCK_OUT = 2015-12-31 07:38:07

but the result for the USER_WORK_HOURS ended up being 00:20:15. Which does not make sense to me. The only thing that it looks like it did was take the year 2015 and broke it up into the TIME format in the database?

Is that what happened? Am I using the wrong format for that column?

What is the right way to go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Problem solved thanks to Ashok Chitroda and Jorge Torres here is the corrections I had to make

```
$uhours = $uclockout-$uclockin;
```

to

```
$uhours = date('H:i:s' , (strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00'))+ strtotime($uclockout) - strtotime($clockin) ));
```

and also I spelled a variable wrong.

Thank you everyone

Comment: have you tried date_diff function?

Comment: @JTheDev I did see that, but was unsure of how to use that. Is it just a PHP function?

Comment: @JTheDev actually yes, I did try this. I put in the $uclockin and $uclockout in as the parameters and it told me I had the wrong parameters. can it not accept variables as parameters?

Comment: USE This Example For better understanding:
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

Comment: @Kunal but what if I want to grab the 2 times from the database?

Comment: @Ddrossi93: I've got a wild idea, 
`$t1 = 1451545437;
$t2 = 1451546420;
$dt1 = new DateTime(date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $t1));
$dt2 = new DateTime(date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $t2));
$diff = date_diff($dt2, $dt1, true);
echo "y = ".$diff->y;
echo " m = ".$diff->m;
echo " d = ".$diff->d;
echo " h = ".$diff->h;
echo " i = ".$diff->i;
echo " s = ".$diff->s;` Try this and see... $diff is an object and you can get the relevant properties like hour minutes seconds or date, etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
$uhours = $uclockout-$clockin;
```

to

```
$uhours = date('H:i:s' , (strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00'))+ strtotime($uclockout) - strtotime($clockin) ));
```

Comment: Tried this and the results don't make much sense for this either. Clock_in = 2015-12-31 08:15:24. Clockout = 2015-12-31 08:15:29. and the difference came out to be 00:47:13.

Comment: user Jorge Torres caught the error the variable $clockin should be $uclockin, but combined with your answer, this works perfectly. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

might you be using the wrong variable in the subtraction?

```
$uclockin = $data->row()->USER_CLOCK_IN;

$uclockout = date(('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

$uhours = $uclockout-$clockin;
```

Note $uclockin Vs $clockin

Comment: you are correct there. Nice catch. Now the difference between the times is coming up as 00:00:00

Comment: Now combine with the answer by Ashok Chitroda :)

Comment: beautiful. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Use timestampdiff(UNIT, FIRST TIMESTAMP, SECOND TIMESTAMP) in your query.
[Follow this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

Comment: is that in the database using SQL? or a PHP function?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

SQL

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
$to_time = $clockin;
$from_time =$uclockout;
$a= round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60);

echo ($a/60).' Hours';
```

if your $clockin is not in timestamp pleas convert date into timestamp
like this eg.

```
$to_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 09:42:00");
$from_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 11:42:00");
$a= round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60);

echo ($a/60).' Hours';
```